# Send complex objects with cross references using web services JAVA and Axis2

Tags: json, web-services, reference

Hi guys this is my first post in Stack Overflow, I'm a student and new develop in Java and I'm trying to solve a problem.

I have a objects structure and I'm trying to send it by web service to consume in an android application.
The problem is because this structure have a lot of cross references.

Now I'm trying to use Axis2 returning an object, but this give me an error because I use enums. And before this I tried to send a JSON in a String, but have problems creating the JSON with cross references.

In my structure I have classes, Interfaces, inheritances, abstracts classes and 
generics.

I spent a lot of time in this trying to solve it. But when I solve one thing I have a new problem.

What is the best approach to solve this?